# Importing a binary file into MASM (equivalent to incbin directive on NASM)

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm, masm

I'm looking for a simple way to produce an EXE file on Windows using the standard tools with Visual Studio e.g. ml, cl, link etc.

For example, using NASM it's possible to do:

```
; $ nasm -f win64 prog1.asm -o prog1.o
; $ x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld prog1.o -o prog1.exe
Global Start
Start:
    incbin "img01.bin"
```

Comment: MASM doesn't have an equivalent directive. You will have to write a tool that emits your binary input into an output file as a series of `db` directives. Then you can include that generated file.